# how i can move image with keys in C# window store app

Tags: c#, .net, windows-store-apps

How i can move image with arrows keys in C# window store app?

In XAML I placed an image that I want to move on arrow keys

```
<Image Name ="Blue"  Grid.Column="11" Source="Assets/Blue.jpg"/>
```

In C#, I bind Keydown event but my code to move image up/down/right/left is not working.

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(MainPage_KeyDown);
}

private void MainPage_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Right)
        Blue.HorizontalAlignment += 30;
    else if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Left)
        Blue.HorizontalAlignment -= 1;
    else if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Up)
        Blue.VerticalAlignment += 1;
    else if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Down)
        Blue.VerticalAlignment -= 1;
}
```

Comment: *At least* tell us what's happening with this code. At least. Is the event even getting called? Sometimes having controls on top of controls will mark `KeyDown` events as handled, so they won't traverse the tree up to your `MainPage`. Setting a breakpoint would tell you if that was occurring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To explicitly define location of child you have to use Canvas. According to MSDN documentation of [Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Canvas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.canvas):

> Defines an area within which you can explicitly position child objects, using coordinates that are relative to the Canvas area.

Simple put your image in canvas

```
<Canvas>
    <Image x:Name="BlueImage" Source="Assets/Blue.png" />
</Canvas>
```

And to move image up/down/left/right with key down you can use below C# code.

```
private void HandleKeyDown(Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow sender, Windows.UI.Core.KeyEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.VirtualKey == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Right)
        Canvas.SetLeft(BlueImage, Canvas.GetLeft(BlueImage) + 30);
    else if (args.VirtualKey == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Left)
        Canvas.SetLeft(BlueImage, Canvas.GetLeft(BlueImage) - 30);
    else if (args.VirtualKey == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Up)
        Canvas.SetTop(BlueImage, Canvas.GetTop(BlueImage) - 30);
    else if (args.VirtualKey == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Down)
        Canvas.SetTop(BlueImage, Canvas.GetTop(BlueImage) + 30);
}
```

Using [Canvas.SetLeft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.canvas.setleft.aspx) and [Canvas.SetTop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.canvas.settop.aspx) you can tell Canvas where to place specific child from left and top respectively.

**EDIT:** To register KeyDown events you have to override OnNavigatedFrom and OnNavigatedTo methods.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);

    Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyDown -= HandleKeyDown;
}

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyDown += HandleKeyDown;
}
```